# Probability Defective Items Binomial Distribution

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

Suppose that a large lot with 10000 manufactured items has 30 percent defective items and 70 percent nondefective. You choose a subset of 10 items to test.
(a) What is the probability that at most 1 of the 10 test items is defective? 
(b) Approximate the previous answer using the binomial distribution.

I am getting for (a) that $P(\text{at most 1 def item}) = 0.7^{10} + {10\choose 1} \cdot 0.3^1 \cdot 0.7^9$

I do not understand what is meant by (b), since the answer for (a) already uses binomial distribution?

Answer (score 1):

The $10$ items are not chosen independently since they are chosen without replacement.  If it were with replacement, with a tiny chance that the same item might be chosen more than once, then the binomial distribution would be exact rather than a very close approximation.  As it is, part (a) must use a hypergeometric distribution.  The answer you've written for part (a) is in fact a correct answer to part (b).

Comment: so the answer for (a) would be 3000C0 * 7000 C 10 / 10000 C 10 +3000 C1 * 7000 C9 /10000 C 10 ?

Comment: @DeeChantelle Yes.

Comment: The hypergeometric distribution has the same expected value as the binomial distribution and a very slightly smaller variance.  If instead of 10000 there were only 40, then the variance of the hypergeometric distribution would be far smaller, but the variance of the binomial distribution would still be the same.

Answer (score 0):

The binomial distribution is only an approximation

More explicitly

$P(\text{at most 1 defective }) = P(\text{ no defective item}) + P(\text{1 defective item}) \\= \frac{7000}{10000}\frac{6999}{9999}\ldots \frac{6991}{9991}  + 10 \frac{3000}{10000}\frac{7000}{9999}\frac{6999}{9998} \ldots \frac{6992}{9991} $